# How to open Siebel in IE8 instead of Chrome

Tags: siebel

I installed Siebel 8.1 version with sample database in my system (Windows 7 OS). I have both IE8 and chrome installed in my machine. Whenever I open Siebel Client, it opens in chrome by default.

To change my IE as default browser, I opened IE and navigated to Tools->Internet Options->Programs and checked "Tell me if IE is not the default browser" and also clicked "Make default" button. Once those changes are made, I restarted my IE.

Even after I made IE as my default browser, Siebel Client still opens in chrome. Now my all other applcations are opening in IE by default except Siebel Client. I do not want to uninstall chrome as well.

Is there anyother way to resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this,if you’re using 64-bit Windows, add the following to your Web Client shortcut. This ensures that the 32-bit version of IE is in use: /b “C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe”

Comment: If you're using the 32-bit Windows version, the path would be the same, without the "(x86)" part. Also, by adding the /b option, you can set Chrome again as your default browser :)